# Proving that $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z}[i])$ is a lattice in $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{C})$

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, lattices

I need to show that $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z}[i])$ is a lattice in $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{C})$. I was thinking of applying Borel-Harish Chandra theorem, which says that:

> Let $G \subseteq \mathrm{GL}_{n}$ be an algebraic group defined over $\mathbb{Q}$, which is semisimple as a Lie group. Then $G(\mathbb{Z}) := G(\mathbb{Q}) \cap \mathrm{GL}(n, \mathbb{Z})$ is a lattice in $G(\mathbb{R})$.

I couldn't formulate it in a way that I can apply Borel-Harish Chandra. How to prove this?

Comment: Take the Weil restriction?